# Unable to save table column value from dropdown in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4.

I' m trying to make a dependent dropdown into my form using ajax. I'm sending the **column_id** and **column** in ajax response to my dropdown. My dropdown is working absolutely fine but there is mess with my either database query or ajax response. My dropdown shows the values of column but when I try to save into database, it only saves the "Id"  of column not the value.

I just wanted to send the **column_id** and **column** both to my dropdown but only save the value into database.

Blade

```
<form action="{{route('form_for_private_sellers')}}>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="make" id="make" data-dependent="model">
       <option value="">Select Make</option>
       <option value="254">Abarth</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <select name="model" id="model">
       <option selected value="">Select Model*</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$("#make").change(function()
{
    var id=$(this).val();
    var make_id = id;

    var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('fetchModel') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{make_id:make_id, _token:_token,dependent:dependent},
        success:function(result)
        {
            $('#'+dependent).html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function fetchModel(Request $request)
{
    $get_make_id = $request->get('make_id');
    $dependent = $request->get('dependent');


    $fetch_model = DB::table('auto_databases_one')
        ->select('model','model_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->where('make_id', '=', $get_make_id)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('is_active', '=', '1');
        })
        ->orderBy('model', 'ASC')
        ->get();

    $show_model = '<option value="">Select ' . ucfirst(dependent) . '</option>';
    foreach ($fetch_model as $row) {
        $show_model .= '<option value="' . $row->model_id . '">' . $row->model . '</option>';
    }
    echo $show_model;
}

public function form_for_private_sellers(Request $request)
{
      $store_seller = new Sellers();
    $store_seller->make = $request['make'];
    $store_seller->model = $request['model'];
}
```

Comment: you did not save anything in your controller method. where is the save part?

Comment: @AndySong 
I don't know what else I should do. 
Could you suggest me the edits please ?

Comment: you should also post the code that inserts smth in the database

Comment: at least you need to tell us what column want to save, into what table basically you need to have another request to post data, you now only have one get request. You should have ajax request when you click save button. And that's the place to  save the record.

Comment: @AndySong
I have updated my question with all code now. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @CornelRaiu
I have updated my question with all code now. Sorry for confusion. Please have a look

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: @AndySong
I was making logic in which your example code helped me a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a button with `id="save"`.

```js
$("#save").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    const make = $("#make option:selected").val();
    const model = $("#model option:selected").val();
    const _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"{{route('form_for_private_sellers')}}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{make, _token, model},
        success:function(result)
        {
            console.log('all done');
        }
    });
});
```

```php
public function form_for_private_sellers(Request $request)
{
    $store_seller = new Sellers();
    
    //you may need to adjust this part as I do not know your properties called.
    $store_seller->make = $request->make;
    $store_seller->model = $request->model;
    
    $store_seller->save();
}
```

Comment: My scenario was not only to submit the values but also to see what's going wrong with my ajax response and that's what I fixed with your code hint. Thanks ..!!!!!!!!!!